# exports.client = client ^ ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

У меня возникла проблема (можно сказать, я новичок в Node js, так что прошу прощения, если что то неправильно делаю). Когда я экспортирую `const client`, у меня выходит данная ошибка:

```
exports.client = client
^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'D:\Lessons\Projects\Remember\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Если я убираю `type: "module"` с package.json, то у меня перестают работать импорты, вот код:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

`database.js`

```
import pkg from "pg";
const { Client } = pkg

export const client = new Client({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "postgres",
    port: 5050,
    password: "said250/",
    database: "forportfolio"
})

exports.client = client
```

`server.js`

```
// Imports
import path from 'path'
import express from "express"
import { client } from '../src/Db/database.js'

// Constant's
const app = express()
const __dirname = path.resolve()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// Uses
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json())

client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('не работает, лох', err.stack)
    } else {
        console.log('ишлади братиш');
    }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Спасибо всем заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если стоит `type="module"` в *package.json*. В качестве модульной системы использует *ES modules* в которой

для импорта используется ключевое слово `import`

```
import path from 'path'
```

для экспорта - ключевое слово `export`

```
export const client = ...
```

Если настройка `type` отсутствует, используется `CommonJS` module, в которой

для импорта используется функция `require`

```
const path = require('path')
```

для экспорта - объект `exports`

```
exports.client = client
```

В коде из вопроса - два подхода смешаны. Нужно выбрать какой-то один.

Comment: Значит нужно будет изменить все импорты в экспорты?

Comment: Или можете подсказать как этот export.client = client можно написать с импортом вместо экспорта?

Comment: @AliakbarSaidov, ты как-то странно читаешь ответ. импорты и экспорты между собой не связаны друг на дружку их не надо менять. У тебя в файле  `database.js` идет попытка сделать два разных вида экспорта. Тебе надо выбрать один

Comment: понятно, прошу прощения, и спасибо вам.